# Prevent knockout textInput data-bind from updating the field value while typing

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have this (very simplified) HTML:

```
<label>Quantity: <input name="quantity" type="number" data-bind="textInput: quantity"/></label>
<label>Euros: <input name="wholeNumber" type="number" data-bind="textInput: wholeNumber"/></label>
```

And this (also very simplified) Knockout model:

```
function ViewModel() {
    self = this;
    cents = ko.observable();
    quantity = ko.observable();
    wholeNumber = ko.computed({
        read: function() {
            return (self.cents() / 100).toFixed(2); 
        },
        write: function(value) {
            self.cents(Math.round(value * 100));
        }
    });
}

ko.applyBindings(ViewModel);
```

See this fiddle for a running example: https://jsfiddle.net/KHFn8/5569/

When I run this code the value of the quantity does not refresh while typing, but the value of the wholeNumber does change after each keystroke.

I have two questions about this:

1. Since both fields have a two way binding why does this only happen in the case of the computed observable (wholeNumber), but not in the case of a normal observable?
2. How can I prevent the updating of the field from happening while I'm still typing. I can use `wholeNumber.extend({ rateLimit: { timeout: 500, method: "notifyWhenChangesStop" } });`, but that's an suboptimal solution.

Comment: Could you please clarify the purpose of the computed being binded to the input area? Will it be used for filtering of user input?

Comment: The reason is that the user enters the price in whole euro's with the cents as decimals but that internally I must use a cents representation.

Comment: Then you perhaps could use the following: make your input field be bounded to the observable `wholeNumber` and add pureComputed `cents` which would be basically your old setter. Pure computed has some performance and memory benefits compared to plain computed, provided it is pure function i.e. has no side effects (doesn't change others except himself) and has no hidden state. https://jsfiddle.net/jnue087v/ for working code sample and http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-pure.html for the details of pureComputed.

Comment: thanks you for the proposal. The problem is that this way the wholeNumber isn't dependant on cents so changing cents (which happens when initially loading the cents value using ajax) won't result in an updated wholeNumber value. What I'd like (I think) is that the field won't be updated until it looses focus. So that wholenumber DOES write to cents, but blocks updates form cents until the field loses focus.

Comment: If I understood the problem properly, "turning the tables" on your original code would be sufficient: just make cents `pureComputed` and wholeNumber `observable` and bind them together - https://jsfiddle.net/uvmqk4sd/1/.

Comment: Yes, that could work I guess. When setting the cents it will actually result in storing it in the wholeNumber and if I want to use cents for calculations then that is also not a problem. Thanks! I'd mark it as the correct answer if it weren't a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an answer to your first question on why it does happen with computed binds but not with normal observables:

Let's consider `wholeNumber` binding. Every time the value of the input field changes, dom-to-computable binding executes setter `write`, which in his turn updates `cents`; because the computed `wholeNumber` depends on `cents` observable it is subscribed to all its changes, so the change of `cents` causes computable-to-dom binding to execute `read` and update the input (and moves the cursor to the the end of the input field). Here is a slightly updated jsfiddle, with logging of getter/setter calls (https://jsfiddle.net/mdydarfb/)

In the case of an ordinary observable, every change of the input field updates only the state of the binded observable without that "chain reaction".

As an answer to the second qustion:

If I understood the problem properly, "turning the tables" on your original code would be sufficient: just make cents pureComputed and wholeNumber observable and bind them together - http://jsfiddle.net/uvmqk4sd/1

Answer (score -1):

1. About `quantity` property. If you want to update it when `wholeNumber` is changing you need to change your `wholeNumber` computed definition. Because now it changes only `cents`:

   ```
   write: function(value) {
       self.cents(Math.round(value * 100));
   }
   ```
2. Regarding `wholeNumber.extend({ rateLimit: { timeout: 500, method: "notifyWhenChangesStop" } });` Why do you think it's suboptimal? It's "official" recipe from the documentation - http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/rateLimit-observable.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's not that I want quantity to change when changing wholeNumber, it's more about WHY its input value does not change while typing it the quantity field itself like the way the wholeNumber changes. Or maybe it does, but I just don't see it because the value doesn't differ from what I type. The rateLimit approach is suboptimal because the cursor is placed at the end of the input field when the ,xx cents part is added. That's annoying.

Comment: Take a look at updated jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/KHFn8/5570/ It seems like `quantity` binding is ok. Maybe I misunderstood the question?

Comment: Yes, the quantity is working fine, that's not the issue. Please reread my previous comment I changed the wording so maybe my question is more clear now.

Comment: I got it. In this case I'd recommend you to "play" with cursor position. For example like in this discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26263169/how-to-retain-cursor-position-when-updating-a-knockout-js-observable-in-an-exten

Comment: Okay, that could work. It just feels hacky. I was wondering if there is something else that I'm doing wrong since the "normal" observable does not have this behavior.

Answer (score -1):

Becauase it has any process in computed function about quantity. You must add quantity in function. For example;

```
wholeNumber = ko.computed({
    read: function() {
        return (self.cents() / 100 * self.quantity()).toFixed(2);
    },
    write: function(value) {
        self.cents(Math.round(value * 100));
    }
});
```